# Cannot browse websites using wireless

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I have Windows XP and, after connecting correctly to the wireless router, cannot browse any websites through any browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE).

- I am connected to the router
- I have an IP (see ipconfig results below)
- I can browse the Internet on my Ubuntu and OSX machines using wireless
- I can browse the Internet on my Windows XP machine  **only when wired**

*ipconfig* results:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

**Summary of OS, hardware, settings**

- Windows XP
- D-Link WBR-2310
- WPA2 Encryption, Personal

Comment: Can you perform nslookup of a public host name? Can you ping any of the resulting IP addresses?  How about telnet to port 80 of those IP addresses... do you get a connection?

Comment: Its encrypted. Do you have the key?

Comment: what ip are you getting?

Comment: I've answered most of these questions by editing the question above.
@BasicallyMoney.com - I held off on most of your questions because I only know how to ping the websites.

Comment: @unknown, you say you're connected to the router via wireless.  Can you browse to the router, 192.168.0.1?

Comment: When you're connected via WiFi, what is the output of "IPCONFIG /ALL"?  Compare to the same command when connected via Ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

Can other systems on your LAN browse the web?

Click **Start >> Control Panel >> Security Center >> Windows Firewall** and check the firewall settings.  If necessary make an exception for one of the browsers, say Firefox, and see if you can then browse the web.

Do you have any other firewall/antispyware software installed that might be blocking Internet access?

Comment: Yes, and I can browse from the same machine when using the LAN, just not the WAN. I've posted more details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you are wired to the router LAN with an ethernet cable?

Go to the Status page on your router ([should look like this](http://support.dlink.com/emulators/wbr2310/st_device.html)).  Under WAN, are you getting an IP address, DNS, subnet mask?  This lets us know if your router can connect to the internet.