# Cannot browse websites using wireless on some Windows machines, but all is fine on a Mac and Linux box

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot browse websites using wireless](https://superuser.com/questions/53076/cannot-browse-websites-using-wireless)

This is a repeat of [Cannot browse websites using wireless](https://superuser.com/questions/53076/cannot-browse-websites-using-wireless) but I did not get any other information that helped.

- I have a Mac and Linux PC which have no problems browsing the web through the WAN.
- Multiple Windows XP PCs (SP3 and SP2) cannot browse the web, although they do connect the the router and get a standard IP address, and I can connect to the routers settings.
- I can browse the web on the windows pcs using an ethernet cable connected to the router.
- Windows firewall has an exception for web browsing (HTTP and internet explorer and firefox)
- I disable the Windows Firewall, updated the wireless drivers and checked for isolation and MAC filtering but there is nothing like that, I have never set this up either.
- The PC connects fine to the internet through a smartphone that also has internet access (I suppose this is similar to being connected through the ethernet cable).
- Disabling encryption doesn't seem to help
- Output of `ipconfig`:

  ```
  Windows IP configuration

  Host name : universi-3f69d5
  Primary DNA suffix :
  Node type : hybrid
  IP routing enabled : No
  WINS Proxy enabled : No

  Ethernet Adapter LAN Connection 2:
  Media state : Media disconnected
  Description : Bluetooth Persona Area Network
  Physical Address : 00-0D-F0-56-92-6F

  Ehternet adapter Wireless Network Connection;
  Connection specific DNS suffix :
  Description : Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
  Physical Address : 00-1C-BF-76-94-92
  DHCP enabled : YES
  Autoconfiguration enabled : Yes
  IP address : 10.0.0.4
  Subnet mask : 255.255.255.0
  Default gateway : 10.0.0.2
  DHCP server : 10.0.0.2
  Lease obtained - Thursday, December 16 2010, 12:20
  Lease expires - Thursday, December 16, 13:20
  ```

I once read about Web/Winsocket resetting in windows, but I can't seem to find anything, any further ideas ?

Comment: Liam, the missing "delete" link was caused by your multiple accounts, [1](http://superuser.com/users/59381/liam-thompson), [2](http://superuser.com/users/59105/liam-thompson). I've asked a moderator to merge them into one. If you have even more accounts, then please ask a moderator to merge those too?

Answer (score 0):

If the other question was by you, I hope you have tried everything there - if it wasn't you, please edit the question and put  your ipconfig output in it like the other question.

Quite frankly, you have done most steps that I would recommend/try, and all I can really suggest is a few solutions.

1) Go to network connections and choose disable for all connections apart from Wireless.

2) Update your wireless network card drivers.

3) Check router wireless settings for any sort of "advanced" wireless configuration options such as isolation or MAC filtering.

Answer (score 0):

try to ping the gateway when you're connected via wlan.
Also try to ping ips from websites (ping 64.34.119.12 for superuser.com :) ).
If this works try to ping superuser.com

Please post the results after that.

Note: you could also check if automatic proxy configuration is enabled. Normally it should not cause problems but to be on the safe side, disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Open IE and do a reset using the Internet Options> Advanced tab, this can fix many connectivity issues for any software that tries to connect to the internet, including other browsers, Windows Media Player, etc.

Winsock reset....http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259